# Covariance and independence for Student-t distribution

Tags: covariance, t-distribution

It is well-known that $Cov(X,Y)=0$ means independence if $(X,Y)$ is bi-normal distributed, would this be true for Student-t distributions? If not, could anyone give an counter-example.
Great thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true for Student-t distributed random variables. Consider the following example:
$$
T_1 = \frac{Z_1}{\sqrt{V/v}}, \quad
T_2 = \frac{Z_2}{\sqrt{V/v}},
$$
where $Z_1, Z_2$ are standard normally distributed and $V$ is chi-squared distributed with $v$ degrees of freedom. [$T_1$ and $T_2$ are Student-t distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Characterization)$^1$, their correlation is zero,

$$\text{Cov}[T_1, T_2] = \text{E}[T_1 T_2] - \text{E}[T_1]E[T_2] = v \text{E}\left[\frac{Z_1 Z_2}{V}\right] = 0,$$

but they are not independent. If $V$ is small, both $T_1$ and $T_2$ will tend to take on larger values. This is difficult to see in a joint histogram but becomes visible in a conditional histogram:

[image]
[image]

Note how the values of $T_2$ are more spread out when $T_1$ takes on a large value.

$^1$Also, $T_1$ and $T_2$ are jointly [multivariate t-distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_t-distribution).